# I wrote a palindrome checking function. Why is it always returning true regardless of what string I input?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, palindrome

Every time I make changes after the first few lines no matter what I do the function is always true. I know there are other issues to address with checking for palindromes, but I'm just looking to fix whatever bug is causing this.

```
const palindromes = function (str) {
const arr = Array.from(str)
const arr2 = arr.reverse()



for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] !== arr2[i]){
    return false
    }
    else if (arr[i] === arr2[i] && i < (arr.length - 1)){
        continue
    }
    else {
        return true
    } 


}


};
```

Answer (score 0):

Arr.reverse() mutates the original arr object, that leads you to compare two of the same arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The function `.reverse()` reverses the array on which it is called, i.e it reverses inplace. Hence your variable `arr` gets reversed and gets compared with `arr2` has the same value as `arr`.

Instead of `const arr2 = arr.reverse()` try `const arr2 = arr.slice().reverse()`

It will first create a copy of arr and then reverse it and store the variable in arr2

Comment: ok thank you. I figured it had something to do with that line because it seemed to return true regardless of what I did after it.